# Sending ASCII text to RAW printer via TCP socket

Tags: sockets, printing, plc

I'm sending text to a RAW printer (HP Laser-jet) from an Allen-Bradley PLC (programmable logic controller) using a TCP socket connection to port 9100. I'm able to send plain text, line breaks, tabs, etc. with no issues.

Is there a way to send commands that would allow me to format some of the text as bold or in a different font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's harder than it used to be (with old matrix printers) but the good news is that most HP laserprinters, and many competitors, still understand [PCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language).  Have a look at the documentation (links at the bottom of the Wikipedia page).  For example, in the [PCL5 technical reference manual part 1](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-bpl13210) you can see that there is a command to change the stroke weight (from -7 ultra thin over 0 normal to 7 ultra black), like this:

Normal text<kbd>Esc</kbd>(s3BBold text<kbd>Esc</kbd>(s0BNormal text